# Best practice to update UI from BroadcastReceiver (for receive new sms)

Tags: android

I have an activity for display new sms and SmsReceiver (extends BroadcastReceiver) to receive incoming sms. After receive sms, what is the best practice to update the UI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well if you have your own activity it is obious that you want you activity to be shown after the user receive a sms. Then in your receiver , onReceive method you can do this

```
startActivity(new Intent(context,MyActivity.class));
```

and the activity is presented to the user...

If you want to put additional info you can use putExtra("key","value") (it is method from the intent)
you can use like

```
Intent i=new Intent():
i.putExtra("key","value");

startActivity(context,i);
```

then in the activity onCreate method you can get this info by

```
String value = intent.getStringExtra("key");
```

and like this you can implement your business logic

Edit

when the activity is already running you can use

android:launchMode=["multiple" | "singleTop" |
                              "singleTask" | "singleInstance"]

I think singleInstance and singleTask will keep only one instance of your activity

Comment: If my activity is current running, does this start another activity?

Comment: in you manifest you can add singleTask and that solves this kind of scenario,see my edits

Comment: Thankyou, I managed to make it work with your help and a bit code

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using `BroadcastReceiver` there is no reason to use `startActivity()` as Lukap suggests. Simply *use* the receiver to actually receive messages.

When the SMS have arrived and you want to update the UI, do something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SOME_FANCY_NAME);
String msg = String.format("%d new SMS(s)!", numNewSMS);
intent.putExtra(SOME_FANCY_NAME_EXTRA, msg);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Then, in your activity:

```
class MyMessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equals(SOME_FANCY_NAME)) {
      // Here goes your UI-updates

      String msg = intent.getStringExtra(SOME_FANCY_NAME_EXTRA);
      Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't updates the UI but shows a Toast only. I guess he wanted to update the UI of a ListActivity or so.

Comment: Please learn how to read before downvoting answers, and stop extrapolating data that's not there. OP wrote "display the new sms" in his first comment. The purpose of a toast is *exactly* what OP wanted. No more, no less.