# How can I use a view model, with sqlite and a broadcast receiver to update the UI?

Tags: android, kotlin, observable, android-livedata

I have an application that is used for testing connectivity, it has a 20min alarm, and must contact a server with a unique code, and the server sends an sms with the same code to confirm.
I have all the components working, but I don't know how to get the unique code to automatically update in the UI.
The alarm writes each request into an sqlite DB, and I would like that to automatically update the UI using an observable.

My project is in Kotlin if that makes any difference.

Basically, I'm just not figuring out how to "observe" the sql database for changes or how to have the broadcast receiver and the activity use the same observable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858398/best-practice-to-update-ui-from-broadcastreceiver-for-receive-new-sms

Comment: The answer to that question uses an intent or a broadcast receiver. I don't need to start my application when the alarm fires or when the sms receives, I just need the UI to sync with the database IF it is open. If I can't figure out the livedata and observables, I'm strongly considering using a listener on sharedprefs in my UI.

Comment: can you please show code ? what have you tried ?

Comment: I haven't finished implementing this all the way yet, but, for starters, I changed my activity to a LifeCycleOwner, and created a MutableLiveData singleton. In my main activity, I put an observer on the MutableLiveData, and then when the alarm updates, it can data.post("value") which will replicate to the UI. In my case, this is fine for live updates from the alarm/receiver, but I also need to do something similar from sqlite, which I will work on a bit later, then post the code.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is not complete yet:**

In order to do what I wanted, I have so far implemented a shared prefs listener and use that to relay data between the broadcast receivers and the UI. I also implemented an observable object with the new libraries, but I needed to run the app on an older device, so the observable didn't work.

```
private val listener = SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener { prefs, key ->
    val value = prefs.getString(key, "")
    when(key) {
        "sms" -> smsStatus.text = value
    }
} 
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_smschecker)
    //setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    getSharedPreferences("SMS_CHECKER", MODE_PRIVATE).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener)
}
```

then in the broadcast receiver:

```
val editor = context.getSharedPreferences("SMS_CHECKER", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
    editor.putString("sms", DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Date()))
    editor.apply()
```

Still working on the sqlite monitoring.